# ASP.NET MVC Clientside validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

For some reason - the MVC custom client side required field validation is not working  - Here is the Model we have -

```
public class PersonalDetailsViewModel : OnboardingViewModel
{
  [RequiredLocalized]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  ....
}

public class RequiredLocalizedAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return " This field is mandatory";
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (base.IsValid(value))
        {   
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        //string errorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName);
        string errorMessage = ErrorMessageString;

        // The value we set here are needed by the jQuery adapter
        var requiredLocalizedRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
            ValidationType = "requiredlocalized"
        };
        yield return requiredLocalizedRule;
    }
}    

  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredlocalized", function (options) {
        options.rules["requiredlocalized"] = "true";
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredlocalized", function (value) {
        return value.length > 0;
    });
```

when i tab out of this field without providing any input nothing happens

HTML Output

```
<input class="customText " data-val="true" data-val-length="Max length is 20 characters only"    
data-val-length-max="20" data-val-requiredlocalized="The field {0} is invalid." 
id="personalDetailsFirstName" maxlength="20" name="PersonalDetailsView.FirstName" 
title="firstName" type="text" value="" />
```

Could any one guide me on what could have gone wrong?.Appreciate your help

Comment: What happens when you try to submit the form? (note its lazy validation so just tabbing out wont necessarily trigger the validation - it should work if you type something, then clear it, the tab out). It also does not appear you have defined the message in the `adapters.add` function.

Comment: @StephenMuecke tried that no luck ?

Comment: Copied your code to my project and client side validation works. Looking at your html it appears you have manually written it instead of using strongly typed helpers, so not surprised it does not work for you.